# How do I address this KeyError?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use python to build a program for a finance portfolio optimization. I am coming up with a Key Error: Date. Here is he segment where the key error occurs:

```
#create a dataframe to store the adjusted close price of the stocks
df = pd.DataFrame()

#store the adjusted close price of the stock into the df
for stock in assets:
  df[stock] = web.DataReader(stock, data_source='yahoo', start= stockStartDate , end = today)['Adj Close']
```

---

Here is the Error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:
```

Comment: you are getting an error and not creating a dataframe, therefore it cannot find 'Date'    Just try df for the first stock and see if that creates the dataframe

Comment: What type of object does web.DataReader return?